# Landing pages for fans ant non-fans. After like click redirect to wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I have two landing pages for fans and non-fans. After like click Im redirected to fans
landing page. Is it possible to redirect visitor to wall page(not fans landing page) after he clicks the like button for the first time ?

I would be appreciated for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Seamless way to check if user likes page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329818/seamless-way-to-check-if-user-likes-page)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display content after clicking Facebook Like button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414768/display-content-after-clicking-facebook-like-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple and easy!
https://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=190322544333196&topic=4580

found it after 3hours of shuffling keywords on google.

Comment: That link seems to be broken now. Does anyone know what it said?