# How can I find out if a user has clicked the Facebook Like button on my website?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-like

I want to include content on my website which will only be displayed if the user has clicked the Facebook Like button on the very same page. I see in the documentation there is the "edge.create" event which I can subscribe to but won't that only fire when the user likes the page the very first time? If a user has already liked the page, I want him to be able to come back and download again without having to unlike and then like again.

I also notice that this information can be queried through FQL and the likes but it's not clear what the auth requirements are for this.

Is it possible to do this in some way without extra authentication? I want there to only be a single step for the user if he is already logged in.

Answer (score 4):

Check out these two links to see if they can help you:

This one covers the edge.create: [Display content after clicking Facebook Like button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414768/display-content-after-clicking-facebook-like-button)

This one covers if a person has already "liked" a page: [How to check if a user likes my Facebook Page or URL using Facebook's API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/check-if-user-liked-page)

Comment: The first will not work since it has to work for users who have already liked. The second seems to be geared towards Facebook apps. This is not a Facebook app. Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I am unsure as I have not done this myself. You might want to post on the fourm on Facebook - http://forum.developers.facebook.net/ If I find anything else I will post a comment on here.

Comment: I just found this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/visible-to-connection/

Comment: Yeah, but that's legacy FBML... old crufty stuff.