# How can I display a popup window with a message after a user clicks the Facebook like button?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I'm a beginner and new to this sort of thing. I already have a like button on my website, but I want to display a popup window when a user clicks that like button. I've researched this extensively, but everything I've tried doesn't seem to work as many of the posts were outdated - such as this: [Display content after clicking Facebook Like button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414768/display-content-after-clicking-facebook-like-button)

When I try to implement the code the like button disappears entirely.

Can someone show me a working implementation? 
Thanks!

The facebook api has something generic:

```
FB.Event.subscribe(event, callback)
```

I need that to tie into a popup window.

Comment: Lets see some code please!

Comment: That's a great idea and something I initially thought of but didn't know how to do. How would I go about implementing that? could you post an answer? Thanks!

Comment: Never mind. What if the like is not registered on facebook's Server. I would use the Graph API. If you're a beginner, you still need to know the JavaScript basics, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If using the Graph API, it would be like:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(url, likeButtonElement){
  if(url === 'replace this String with like url String'){
    // do something with DOM maybe using likeButtonElement
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do this if I'm simply using a basic script without using Facebook's graph API? I mainly am a Java programmer and have been doing a bit of web design on the side. I simply need to make a popup window after a like on a basic website.

Comment: Not exactly. You won't really be able to tell if the Client has `subscribe`d to the like or not. Since the response comes back from facebook's Server Asynchronously, using this methodology you will know. If you simply put your like button within another Element and test it `onclick` that won't guarantee the like was counted at facebook.